# Passing values to a nested component in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Is there a better way to pass values to a nested component in Storybook? I can explicitly state each individual value, but that seems very inefficient.

```
function Dropdown({ label, type, size, title, disabled }) {
    return (
    <div className="dropdown">
        <Button
            label={label}
            type={type}
            size={size}
            title={title}
            disabled={disabled}
        />
    </div>
)}
```

Is there a way to pass all the values at once?

dropdown.stories.js

```
export const DropdownButton = Template.bind({});
DropdownButton.args = {
    label: "Dropdown label",
    type: "btn-primary dropdown-toggle",
    size: "btn-sm",
    title: "",
    disabled: false,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator:

```
function Dropdown(props) {
    return (
    <div className="dropdown">
        <Button {...props} />
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Do I need to set a PropType for `props`? Or do I need to change how I set the values in the story? As written, it isn't working.

Comment: Adding a PropType won't make any difference in this case. Can you clarify what you mean by it isn't working? Are you getting a compilation error? What happens if you console log `props` in the `Dropdown` components?

Comment: `Object { props: undefined }` - I've added the relevant portion of the stories file for reference.

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to remove the other properties I had defined and use `props.property-name`